# How do I compare two arrays to find common elements (random numbers vs. user input)?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a lottery number program that accepts 10 guesses from the user between the numbers 1-25. The user guesses are stored in the user array. If the user enters the wrong value (< 1 or > 25) the number will not be stored within the user array. The program stores 10 random numbers in another array. So, two arrays in total.

How to compare the two arrays to find common elements, to let the user know how many correct guesses the user made compared to the random numbers array? For this part, I am only allowed to use loops.

I have tried using continue; below the first If, but that messes things up.

I have tried to move the ending curly brackets for the first for-loop to below the first If, but that also messes things up at the "compare the two arrays" part.

```
//User array
int[] användarTal = new int[10];

//Random numbers array
int[] slumpadeTal = new int[10];

//Generator for 10 random numbers.
Random randomerare = new Random();

    //Foor-loop for storing user's 10 guesses in the user array.           
    for (int i = 0; i < användarTal.Length; i++)
    {
         Console.Write("Enter your guess: ");
         string input = Console.ReadLine();
         int num = Convert.ToInt32(input); 
         användarTal[i] = num;

        //If the user enters wrong value
        if (num < 1 || num > 25)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Wrong! You must enter a number between 1-25!");
             användarTal[i] = i--;  //Wrong number will not be stored in the user array.                    
        }
        // continue; 
 // } 

        //For-loop for storing and writing out the 10 random numbers.
        for (int j = 0; j < slumpadeTal.Length; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(randomerare.Next(1, 26));  
            
            // Checking if the two arrays have any common numbers
            if (användarTal[i] == slumpadeTal[j])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(användarTal[i]);
            }
    }
```

I found this solution which I have tried to implement into my program, but I can't get the program to run the way it's supposed to.

```
            int[] arr1 = { 12, 5, 45, 47, 22, 10 };
            int[] arr2 = { 23, 45, 10, 58, 78, 77, 46 };

            for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr2.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (arr1[i] == arr2[j])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(arr1[i]);
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
            int[] arr1 = { 12, 5, 45, 47, 22, 10 };
            int[] arr2 = { 23, 45, 10, 58, 78, 77, 46 };

            for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr2.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (arr1[i] == arr2[j])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(arr1[i]);
                    }
                }

            }
```

I dont see an issue with this code, seems like it should execute fine.
However you can optimise this using Linq

```cs
int[] array1 = { 12, 5, 45, 47, 22, 10 };
int[] array2 = { 23, 45, 10, 58, 78, 77, 46 };
        
int[] commonElements = array1.Intersect(array2);
        
Console.WriteLine("Common Elements: {0}", string.Join(",", commonElements));
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to store and guess *unique* numbers only.
To be sure that numbers are unique, let's use `HashSet<int>` instead
of arrays:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// Random numbers array
HashSet<int> slumpadeTal = Enumerable
  .Range(1, 25)
  .OrderBy(item => Random.Shared.NextDouble())
  .Take(10)
  .ToHashSet();
```

Then let's ask user to guess

```
HashSet<int> användarTal = new HashSet<int>();

while (användarTal.Count < slumpadeTal.Count) {
  while (true) {
    Console.Write("Enter your guess: ");

    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int guess) &&
        guess >= 1 && guess <= 25) {
      användarTal.Add(guess);

      break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect guess; it should be 1..25");
  }
}
```

Having both collections filled in you can easily compare them

```
int guessedRight = slumpadeTal
  .Count(item => slumpadeTal.Contains(item));
```